# How do I receive information about a tapped local notification using .onReceive when my iOS app is not running?

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications

**I want to know how to display a certain message when the user clicks on a notification to open the app (when the app is initially closed).**

I was following this tutorial to handle local notifications in SwiftUI: https://blog.techchee.com/handling-local-notification-in-swiftui/

*What I did:*
I implemented a `NotificationHandler` class which inherits from `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`. This was set to the delegate of `UNUserNotificationCenter` using `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = NotificationHandler.shared` in the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` section under AppDelegate. The `NotificationHandler` class requests permission, schedules notifications, and posts notifications.

The NotificationHandler has these functions:

```swift
/** Handle notification when app is in background */
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response:
        UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        // Assign the response name to a struture under NSNotification.Name
        let notiName = NSNotification.Name(response.notification.request.identifier)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:notiName , object: response.notification.request.content)
        print("background notification")
        completionHandler()
    }

    /** Handle notification when the app is in foreground */
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification,
             withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let notiName = NSNotification.Name( notification.request.identifier )
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:notiName , object: notification.request.content)
        print("foreground notification")
        completionHandler(.banner)
    }
```

I also wrote an `.onReceive(pub)` function in my main view. I wrote a print statement in my .onReceive function to see when it receives a notification. I am testing out the functionality by scheduling the notification for 15 seconds after startup.

*The issue:*
The app seems to only receive the notification when the app is currently running. When I close out the app and then click on the notification, the print statement in .onReceive does not print anything.

*The question:*
**Does anyone know how to receive information about what notification was tapped on using onReceive when iOS app is not running?**

My best guess is that the main view is not running while the app is closed so the onReceive does not work. I saw on another post that recommended using background tasks but I am not familiar with using this to respond to notifications. Other posts seem to just recommend setting `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = NotificationHandler.shared` in the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` section under AppDelegate, but I have already done that.

Comment: This is [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions). When the app is in the background, you have to set up the `AppDelegate` to handle it.